# Using Divs instead of ul in jquery SlideviewerPro 1.5

Tags: jquery

I am a newcomer to coding and have been using Dreamweaver on a WYSIWYG basis.  I have recently dipped into Jquery and have managed to implement the JQuery SlideshowPro plugin on a page. The problem being that the thumbnails are rather pixelated upon automatic reduction and there isnt much scope for moving the individual thumbnails as there are in an unordered list.

I am wondering if there is a way to manually allocate each individual thumbnail in individual Div's (for ease of use) and the main image to be scrolled/swapped in another Div whilst maintaining the sliding effect on the main image transition only.  I am not concerned with having the thumbnails scroll as it is unlikely I will have enough thumbnails on each page to warrant scrolling.  In effect a disjointed image swap with the sliding transition maintained.

The original code can be can be found on the following page: [gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html](http://gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html) although I want to avoid the use of lists if possible.

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is happening?

Comment: I like this post. Rarely do we get people using a plug-in who properly describe the problem and have shown some effort in figuring things out. +1 A code sample would help though. Try posting on jsfiddle.net and send us the URL.

Comment: @ Barry Chapman, I havent been able to find similar examples, @Diodeus many thanks for the responses, the code can be found on the following page:
http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html
Ideally I would like the thumbnails in individual Divs and also the main image (to be swapped via the slide transition) also in an individual Div so i can control the positioning of each Div through CSS if necessary.

I havent been able to post the code on jsfiddle as I dont even know where to begin amending the code to implement what I have explained.

Comment: I looked at the script and it would be a considerable amount of work to change this behaviour. Alternately, you can use lists, but put class names on the LI elements and cheat using absolute positioning without modifying the script.

Comment: @Diodeus, many thanks, i thought it may be a considerable undertaking and probably beyond me at this stage.  I will look at putting class names and using Li as you mention, will this mean i will be able to control and insert individual thumbnails or still rely on the script to generate the thumbnails?

Comment: Putting class names on the LIs will allow you to reposition them using CSS. You can use absolute positioning. It's a little hack-ish but in this situation it's the best you can do.

Comment: @ Diodeus Many thanks Diodeus, i will have a look at how to implement what you describe as my knowledge of coding is basic to say the least.  I will try creating idividual thumbs as li elements and apply the behaviour.

Comment: You are trying to use divs instead of li's? have you tried removing the ul tag and changing the li's to divs then changing their css display to inline?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly this should be pretty easy to do with a simple modification to the plugin and a slight change to the li's images.

First I'd add a data attribute to the image tag in the li specifying a separate thumb url, for example:

```
<li><img alt="Blerg." src="images/blerg.jpg" data-thumb-src="src="images/blerg_thumb.jpg" /></li>
```

I've added a html 5 data attribute called data-thumb-src to contain the thumb path.

Then modify the part of the plugin that builds the thumb images part of the slideshow. I've downloaded the plugin, around line 99 there's this:

```
jQuery(this).find("li").each(function(n) { 
    jQuery("div#thumbSlider" + j + " ul").append("<li><a title='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt") + "' href='#'><img width='"+ thumbsWidth +"' height='"+ thumbsHeight +"' src='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src") + "' /><p class='tmbrdr'>&nbsp;<\/p><\/a><\/li>");                      
});
```

Swap this out for something like this:

```
jQuery(this).find("li").each(function(n) { 
    jQuery("div#thumbSlider" + j + " ul").append("<li><a title='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt") + "' href='#'><img width='"+ thumbsWidth +"' height='"+ thumbsHeight +"' src='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("data-thumb-src") + "' /><p class='tmbrdr'>&nbsp;<\/p><\/a><\/li>");                       
});
```

So the thumbs src now equals the data-thumb-src from the main image.

If you're feeling really adventurous you could try something like this and use the normal thumb by default and then the custom thumb when you need it on an ad-hoc basis:

```
jQuery(this).find("li").each(function(n) { 
    if( jQuery(this).find("img").attr('data-thumb-src') ){
        var thumb_src = jQuery(this).find("img").attr('data-thumb-src');
    }else{
        var thumb_src = jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src");
    }
    jQuery("div#thumbSlider" + j + " ul").append("<li><a title='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt") + "' href='#'><img width='"+ thumbsWidth +"' height='"+ thumbsHeight +"' src='" + thumb_src + "' /><p class='tmbrdr'>&nbsp;<\/p><\/a><\/li>");                     
});
```

So if the thumb src exists use it, else use the normal thumb.

Hope this helps.